# Opening NAT type with another router?

Tags: networking, router, nat, gaming

I’m not too familiar with networking but in order to play a game with my friends (For Honor) I need an open NAT type. The issue is, I live in an apartment and don’t have access to the router to open the ports to accomplish this. I have Ethernet and was wondering if I connected my own router if I would be able to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain your current setup a little more. Do you have a shared internet connection with the rest of your apartment building, or do you have your own internet service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The apartment router doesn't care whether it's PC/XboxStation asking it for NAT bypass or whether it's another router doing the same. All devices follow the same rules.

So if you connected a 2nd router to the already existing one, it wouldn't be able magically alter or bypass the existing NAT layer; usually it'd just add a *second* one, making things worse.